# Issue on Windows Authentication pop up

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently i am working on a project, where i am facing Windows Authentication Pop up. To handle this pop up I am using Robot class.It is working fine also. But my main problem is that, the same pop up comes again and again dynamically. How can i control this? Can anyone please help me in this regards? I have written below code to control one Windows Pop up.

```
StringSelection username = new StringSelection("Username");
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(username, null);            
                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
                rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
                rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

                //tab to password entry field
                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                Thread.sleep(2000);

                //Enter password by ctrl-v
                StringSelection pwd = new StringSelection("Password");
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(pwd, null);
                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
                rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
                rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

                //press enter
                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); 
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create/modify the method isAlertPresent as given below and try it. It may help you.

First confirm with below method if the alert present

```
public boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try{
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
       return true;
    }
    catch (NoAlertPresentException noAlert) {
      return false;
    }
    catch (TimeoutException timeOutEx){
      return false;
    }
}
```

It's an authentication pop-up. You can handle it like below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);      
Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());     
alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(username, password));
```

OR

```
driver.get("http://UserName:Password@Example.com");
```

OR

If above not work then JavascriptExecutor worked for you. Just take care that you should execute it before clicking the event which invoke alert.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }");
```

Note :- do not use it after clicking on event which invoke alert confirmation box. Above code by default set the confirmation box as true means you are accepting/click on ok on all confirmation box on that page if invoked

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Hi, The code which you have given, It is not working for me . Actually the problem which i am facing ,this is not for web based pop up, but it is windows based pop up. Can you please help me in this regards, whether the code which i have given , which this can i control the dynamic windows based pop up?

Comment: Hi Shubham,Can you please help me in this regards,? Actually i am very new in Selenium.Looking forward to your response.